# Yii2 dropdownlist onchange

Tags: php, yii2

In Yii 1 i could set onchange event for dropDownList by this method:

```
CHtml::dropDownList('id', $select, $list, array('onchange'=>'this.form.submit()'))
```

And it was pretty good. But in Yii 2 it doesn't work, how do i solve this issue?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500793/how-to-create-a-dropdown-dependent-on-another-dropdown-in-yii2/36643901#36643901) may help someone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this code submits on change properly:

```
<?php use yii\helpers\Html; ?>
  <?= Html::beginForm() ?>
  <?= Html::dropDownList(
    'test', //name
    'b',  //select
    ['a'=>'A', 'b'=>'B'], //items
    ['onchange'=>'this.form.submit()'] //options
  )?>
  <?= Html::endForm() ?>
```

Comment: This works unless you have to insert some quoted text. Quotes would convert into special chars. How to ensure quotes won't get converted? This inserted JS won't work: onchange="if($(&quot;#name&quot;).val()==&#039;john&#039;){page.reload();}.

Comment: you can use different quotes or escape symbols: onchange=>"if($('#name').val()=='john'){page.reload();} or you can use JsExpression like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260636/update-hidden-field-using-autocomplete-in-yii2/23261772#23261772